# Jenkins ant build related issues

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-pipeline

ant.bat is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Build step Invoke Ant marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obvious that your job can not find ant.bat in the path.

1. Make sure ant is installed on the node where the job is running. (slave or master)
2. Make sure that the user running the jenkins process/service have ant.bat in PATH. or probably set system path to ant bin.

I can try to help more if you explain your setup. i.e. is it a standalone jenkins server or a distributed environment. What OS is jenkins hosted on (I am assuming windows since you are looking for ant.bat) and how are you trying to invoke ant in the job.

Comment: Thanks, using windows 10 os, I fixed that error.assigned ant home and path in system environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

1. set the **ANT_HOME** in environment variables
2. add **%ANT_HOME%\bin** in the PATH 
   this should solve your issue 
   even after setting ANT_HOME 
   if you facing **'ant.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command**
   restart the Agent/slave , the error will/should disappear.